# Performing Addition on Two Pandas DataFrames by Index Without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of Pandas dataframes where I want to add together the rows that have the same index. For example, say we have two dataframes where their indexes are unordered:

```
      Column1  Column2
Item1       1        4
Item3       2        5
Item2       3        6

      Column1  Column2
Item1       1        3
Item2       2        4
```

Is there a way to add these two dataframes together by index to get the following result with Item3 included? Because a simple df1 + df2 will return the first two lines correctly, but Item3 will end up having NaNs. Having the results become floats is fine.

```
# What I want to calculate
      Column1  Column2
Item1       2        7
Item2       5       10
Item3       2        5

# What actually calculates
      Column1  Column2
Item1     2.0      7.0
Item2     5.0     10.0
Item3     NaN      NaN
```

Comment: try `df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)`

Comment: @rhug123 Very clean and simple, didn't think about using the fill_value parameter as it made it seem that it would just replace the NaNs with zeros. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df_final=(df1.set_index('item').add(df2.set_index('item'), fill_value=0).reset_index())

#float to int

df_final =  df_final.astype(str).replace('\.0','',regex=True).replace(['nan','None'], np.nan)

print(df_final)
```

output

```
   item  col1  col2
0  it1    2    7
1  it2    5   10
2  it3    2    5
```